# convert datetime format DATETIME20. in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert the format of a date using the follow code:

`SELECT convert(datetime, POLIFEIVIG, 106)`

but the following error comes out

`ERROR: CLI describe error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "DATETIME": identificador no v�lido : [Oracle][ODBC]Invalid descriptor 
       index <1>.`

What I can do?

Comment: That convert statement looks like MS-SQL, not Oracle

Comment: What is `datetime`?

Comment: datime is the datatype to convert expression to

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, why would you be storing a date in a column that is not a date?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use SQL Server syntax in oracle...

Try `to_char()` and `to_date()`:

```
select to_char(POLIFEIVIG, 'DD MON YYYY') as TurnDateToText
from MyTable;


select to_date(POLIFEIVIG, 'DD MON YYYY') as TurnTextToDate
from MyTable;
```

Also, Oracle does not have `datetime`. Oracle has `Date` and `Timestamp`

Comment: Just a additional note to the OP that you should only ever use `to_date` on something that is a string. Using it on a date forces implicit conversions to take place (date -> string -> date) and it could potentially fail or return an incorrect date.